# Calling a function in jQuery with click()

Tags: jquery, function

In the code below, why does the **open** function work but the **close** function does not?

```
$("#closeLink").click("closeIt");
```

How do you just *call* a function in `click()` instead of *defining* it in the `click()` method?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#openLink").click(function() {
            $("#message").slideDown("fast");
        });
       $("#closeLink").click("closeIt");
    });

    function closeIt() {
        $("#message").slideUp("slow");
    }
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
Click these links to <span id="openLink">open</span> 
and <span id="closeLink">close</span> this message.</div>

<div id="message" style="display: none">This is a test message.</div>
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
$("#closeLink").click(closeIt);
```

Let's say you want to call your function passing some args to it i.e., `closeIt(1, false)`. Then, you should build an anonymous function and call `closeIt` from it.

```
$("#closeLink").click(function() {
    closeIt(1, false);
});
```

Comment: Quotes are removed from the closeIt function (it took me too long to grok that, so adding a comment to help someone else out).

Comment: @Tiago why no ()? what if you want to pass arguments?

Comment: @Damon: because that way the function will be called and the return of it will be passed to the click function. If you want to pass args, you have to do something like this: $("#closeLink").click(function(){closeIt(some, args, you, 'want');});

Comment: Why not writing a more elaborate answer ? Your last comment should be inside the answer itself ;)

Comment: Why is this bad again? $("#closeLink").click(closeIt(1, false));

Comment: @Dusty: it won't work as expected. Your code will execute the function `closeit` immediately with `1` and `false` as parameters, then the result of that call will be passed as a parameter to `click`. What you want it to call the function `closeit` only when the users clicks the thing.