# jQuery .on() method calling a function inmediatly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm no JavaScript expert (far from it) and I just have superficial experience with jQuery — nothing too fancy. I'm having the following code:

```
    // show search forms
    searchButton = jQuery('#show-search');
    searchForm = jQuery('#search-form');

    function toggleSearch() {
        searchButton.button('toggle');

        searchForm.slideToggle(300, function() {
                searchForm.find('#value').focus();
            });
    }

    searchButton.on('click', toggleSearch());
```

When the page loads, the `#search-form` is in fact activated and it slides down, without the need of calling the function (i.e actually *clicking* the button).

[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447414/calling-a-function-in-jquery-with-click) I can pass the function like this:

```
    searchButton.on('click', toggleSearch);
```

And it will do the same as if I was doing this:

```
    searchButton.on('click', function() {
        toggleSearch();
    });
```

**It works**. Both methods do.

- Why does this work and why can't I just use the first form? (passing `toggleSearch()`)
- What if there is a variable called toggleFunction with some random value? Wouldn't it be passed instead of the function?

**EDIT:** I'm aware of [this excellent answer](http://bit.ly/yQARFv) but it doesn't explain the "reference" part, nor the case of a previously assigned variable. Are annonymous functions neccesary in those cases? Should I just use them every time?

Comment: I think you have the answer to your question.

Comment: @Pablo It's not about the methods working, it's more about _why_ do they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` makes you execute the function, if you use `toggleSearch()`, you are passing the return value(※which in your case is `undefined`) to `.on`, not the function itself.

`toggleFunction` is the function name, but also is a variable, it is same as

```
var toggleFunction = function() {/*...*/};
```

So if there is another variable called `toggleFunction`, the `toggleFunction` will be changed.

Comment: This cleared out a LOT of confusion: "If you use `toggleSearch()`, __you are passing the return value__ (which in your case is undefined) to .on, __not the function itself__." and "... is the function name, __but also a variable__". Now I understand a little bit more about how JavaScript works. +1 to this mate, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `toggleSearch()` you are actually running the function and the return of the function is used as the handler.  When you omit the parentheses you are passing a reference to the function and the function itself will be invoked when the event occurs.

In the case of the two functions that "work", the first is as I've described.  In the second, you're passing an anonymous function reference as the handler. This anonymous function runs the method when it is called, not when it is defined, thus working the same way as passing just the function reference.  If you need to pass arguments to the function, the second method is the way to do that.

```
searchButton.on('click', function() { // this is the handler
    // this is run when the hander executes
    toggleSearch( 'some parameter', 'some other parameter' );
});
```

Comment: The `toggleSearch()` function doesn't return anything, so what would be the "handler" in this case?

Comment: @AeroCross If it doesn't return anything then the handler will be `undefined`.