# JQuery click handler only anonymous function allowed

Tags: jquery

It seems that in jquery click event you can only pass anonymous function. It is not possible to pass a normal javascript function. This lead to problems in my code.

```
function funcCancelClose(testcaseId,update)
{
   if(update == false)
   {
        modalCloseCancel(testcaseId);
   }
   else
   {
        modalCloseCancelUpdate(testcaseId, $("#radio-previous_"+testcaseId).val());
   }
}

var testcaseId = 891;
var update = false;

$("#modalCancel,#modalClose").click(funcCancelClose(testcaseId,update));
```

**This did not work. Even there is no error message in developer console, behavior of code was wrong**

Comment: You're calling the function immediately, not passing a function to call when the click happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function in jQuery with click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447414/calling-a-function-in-jquery-with-click)

Comment: ok so what is the syntax to have it called when the click happens ?

Comment: yeah you are right it is called immediately. That is wrong of course

Comment: It's funny if I pass it as normal function it gets executed, but if I pass it as anonymous function it gets not executed immediately. Why ist that ?

Answer (score 0):

You get your values at html attr like that

```
<span id="modalCancel" data-attr-testcaseId="1" data-attr-update="0"><span>
$("#modalCancel").click(funcCancelClose);
function funcCancelClose(){ console.log($(this).attr('data-attr-testcaseId')); };
```

Comment: Ok. So I have to use a trick to use it as I like to . I have to use a fake html element and put my values there. Hm...

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is calling `funcCancelClose()` immediately, and passing its value as the argument to `click()`.

You can use an anonymous function or use the `bind()` function.

```
$("#modalCancel,#modalClose").click(function() {
    funcCancelClose(testcaseId,update);
});

$("#modalCancel,#modalClose").click(funcCancelClose.bind(null, testcaseId,update));
```

Comment: aha ok. So still I do not understand why normal function is executed immediately but anonymous function is not. But simply I think that is just Jquery implemenation. Right ?

Comment: how come I can call bind on a normal javascript function. What is parameter null . Yeah this works. Thanks.

Comment: It's like the difference between `console.log(1+2)` and `console.log(function() { return 1+2; })`. A function expression just creates a function, it doesn't execute it.

Comment: The first argument to `.bind()` is the value to be given to `this` in the function. It's `null` because your function doesn't use `this`.